# DFS method not working properly

Tags: java, graph, stack

I expect the DFS method to print the path as 1->2->4->5 but it shows 1->2->3->4->5 can you please hint how the method can be fixed with the least amount of code addendum?

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/28/16.
 */

import java.util.Stack;

public class DepthFirstSearch {
    public static void DFS(GraphNode root, int num) {
        if (root.val == num) {
            System.out.println("root has the value "+num);
        }
        System.out.println(" current value is "+root.val);
        Stack<GraphNode> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(root);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            for (GraphNode g : stack.pop().neighbors) {
                if (!g.visited) {
                    System.out.println(" current value is "+g.val);
                    if (g.val == num) {
                        System.out.println("Found");
                    }
                    g.visited = true;
                    stack.push(g);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphNode n1 = new GraphNode(1);
        GraphNode n2 = new GraphNode(2);
        GraphNode n3 = new GraphNode(3);
        GraphNode n4 = new GraphNode(4);
        GraphNode n5 = new GraphNode(5);

        n1.neighbors = new GraphNode[] {n2};
        n2.neighbors = new GraphNode[] {n4,n3};
        n3.neighbors = new GraphNode[] {n4};
        n4.neighbors = new GraphNode[] {n5};
        n5.neighbors = new GraphNode[] {};

        DFS(n1, 5);
    }
}
```

Here's the code for GraphNode class:

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/27/16.
 */
public class GraphNode {
    int val;
    GraphNode next;
    GraphNode[] neighbors;
    boolean visited;

    GraphNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.visited = false;
    }

    GraphNode(int val, GraphNode[] neighbors) {
        this.val = val;
        this.neighbors = neighbors;
        this.visited = false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "value is: "+this.val;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a path to the node, it's insufficient to just add all the nodes that you encounter, since you could run into a "dead end" in the graph or add nodes not actually on the path. To prevent this you need to keep track of the nodes that contained a node as neighbor when you inserted them to the stack:

```
Map<GraphNode, GraphNode> parents = new HashMap<>();
outer: while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    GraphNode currentElement = stack.pop();
    for (GraphNode g : currentElement.neighbors) {
        if (!g.visited) {
            parents.put(g, currentElement);
            System.out.println(" current value is "+g.val);
            if (g.val == num) {
                System.out.println("Found");
                List<GraphNode> path = reconstructPath(parents, g);

                // use path, e.g.
                System.out.println(path.stream().map(n -> Integer.toString(n.val)).collect(Collectors.joining("->")));

                break outer;
            }
            g.visited = true;
            stack.push(g);
        }
    }
}
```

```
static List<GraphNode> reconstructPath(Map<GraphNode, GraphNode> parents, GraphNode end) {
     List<GraphNode> list = new ArrayList<>();
     while (end != null) {
          list.add(end);
          end = parents.get(end);
     }
     Collections.reverse(list);
     return list;
}
```

Comment: so the problem is with using `for (GraphNode g : stack.pop().neighbors) {` ?

Comment: @MonaJalal: Sorry, that was the order in which you pop them from the `Stack`. I didn't recongnize you were printing them when they are added to the Stack... But if you want a path, simply adding all found nodes won't be sufficient... Added a fix for this.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this tomorrow and then accept it as an answer